# Best framework for little 3D application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xna, xna-4.0

I want to write simple application with some 3D objects for Windows OS.

The application is very simple, like a gallery where we can move and see some pictures. When users go to the some picture and click on it a window will open and show picture with some information.

Which is the best framework for this task WPF, XNA, or something else? Application will be written in C#.

Comment: http://axiomengine.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can not say which is best, but I have done a while ago some things with the WPF 3D API and I liked it.

It was IMO very simple to use and the rendering seemed to be relatively fast. A really nice thing I found, was that it has an object-model that contains high-level-events such as mouse-down and click. Therefore you don't have to do much math. However, maybe provide also other APIs such high-level services, I don't know.
I would not try to create an action-game with it, but for a small app as you have described, I think it is worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

[Unity](http://unity3d.com/) has been used for similar stuff. It can work on browsers (via a plug-in) or as a program, has a lot of documentation and most of the work involved in creating a 3D environment and interface is already done. Code can be written in Mono (open source C# implementation), JavaScript or a Boo, a modified Python scripting language.
It works in Windows, MacOS, iPhone, iPad and Android. And it is free in the standard version, or really cheap.

XNA is a little lower level, so it will require more work to get things started. It supports Windows, WP7 and Xbox 360.

Answer (score 0):

See this discussion : [WPF VS XNA](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2701bee3-8a75-498d-b433-fde120a43248/)